# help, django-admin-tools wont work!

Tags: django, django-admin

am installing the django-admin-tools module to enhance the default django admin with custom dashboard and menus. I have read the [docs](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) like a bazillion times

Set up everything the way docs say, but am still merely seeing the Django Admin the SAME WAY is was before I'd even though of django-admin-tools.

What could be wrong?

Am running Django 1.3 and using OpenSuse 11.3

If it helps, the order of apps in my settings.py is like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'admin_tools',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'admin_tools.theming',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'grappelli', #for a sweet django admin look
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django_extensions',
    'fpui', #the footprint front-end ui app
)
```

More Parts of my settings.py in relation to this problem:

```
ROOTDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

ADMIN_TOOLS_MEDIA_URL = ROOTDIR  + '/media/admin_tools/'

MEDIA_ROOT = ROOTDIR + '/media/admin_tools/'

ADMIN_TOOLS_THEMING_CSS = 'css/theming.css'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

ADMIN_TOOLS_INDEX_DASHBOARD = 'footprint.dashboard.CustomIndexDashboard'
ADMIN_TOOLS_APP_INDEX_DASHBOARD = 'footprint.dashboard.CustomAppIndexDashboard'
ADMIN_TOOLS_MENU = 'footprint.menu.CustomMenu'

STATIC_ROOT = ROOTDIR + '/fpui/static/'


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and finally managed to make it work.
I think your `INSTALLED_APPS` are ordered correctly - the `admin_tools` should be before `django.contrib.admin`. To be absolutely sure push `django.contrib.admin` below other admin_tools apps too.
The problem is probably somewhere in the other configurations; mine was that `admin_tools` couldn't access my templates and was running the regular admin instead.

Try the below:

```
ROOTDIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOTDIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'media/static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'your_project_name.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join( PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates' ),
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'admin_tools',
    'admin_tools.theming',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'grappelli', #for a sweet django admin look
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django_extensions',
    'fpui', #the footprint front-end ui app
)
```

Note that I used `realpath` for `ROOTDIR` so that symbolic links may be resolved if there are any. Replace the *your_project_name* with your project name in `ROOT_URLCONF`.
Other parameters such as `ADMIN_TOOLS_INDEX_DASHBOARD`, `ADMIN_TOOLS_APP_INDEX_DASHBOARD` and `ADMIN_TOOLS_APP_INDEX_DASHBOARD` are optional, remove them for now so they won't affect the default configuration.

Of course also make sure your **urls.py** is configured as in the admin_tools guide.

Good luck

Comment: Have a look at your code again: You did not define PROJECT_ROOT, did you?


**EDIT:** just for the sake of completelyness: you can use:
`PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(ROOTDIR, os.path.pardir))`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the order of your INSTALLED_APPS; It might help if you place the django.contrib.admin just below the django-admin-tools, the order here is used for choosing the right /templates/admin directory.

Comment: Indeed, template resolution using `'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'` in the [`TEMPLATE_LOADERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_LOADERS) setting performs lookup in app directories in the order specified by `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: thanks @fijter, but even after doing as you say, still nothing changes! I've added samples from my settings.py to clarify more...

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but I had the same problem, which turned out to be caused by the following circumstance: before installing admin-tools I had overridden one of the admin templates (base-site.html) by putting a modified version in my_project/templates/admin.  So it would always use this template instead of the admin_tools one. After removing the custom template it worked.